# Wrong Password using WhatsAPINet for send WhatsApp in WinForms C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, api, whatsapp

I am thinking of creating an Windows Forms C# application (in Windows 7, Visual Studio 2012, .NET Framework 4.5) and I want use any WhatsApp API to send messages.

I have found this .NET fork of the PHP interface [WhatsAPI for PHP](https://github.com/venomous0x/WhatsAPI)  by Dídac Pérez Parera: https://github.com/perezdidac/WhatsAPINet

I have this test code:

```
string nickname = "WhatsAPI Test";
// 34 = Country Code
// 6xxyyzzmm = mobile number
string sender = "346xxyyzzmm"; // Mobile number with country code (but without + or 00)
string imei = "MY IMEI ANDROID THAT I GET USING *#06#"; // MAC Address for iOS IMEI for other platform (Android/etc) 

var wa = new WhatsApp(sender, imei, nickname, true);
string countrycode = sender.Substring(0, 2);
string phonenumber = sender.Remove(0, 2);

if (!WhatsRegister.ExistsAndDelete(countrycode, phonenumber, imei))
{
  PrintToConsole("Wrong Password");
  return;
}
```

I test, but always I get "Wrong Password"

In my mobile phone, I have installed Whatsapp. It's a Android 4.0.

Any suggestions about it?

Answer (score 4):

Use WART to generate a password

https://github.com/mgp25/WART

Or

https://github.com/shirioko/WART

Comment: if you google 'WhatsApp WART' then still you can find some other links which offer to download it, i haven't tested those links, but i hope you can find a one.